# Transpose tab deliminated textfile with perl using Array::Transpose

Tags: arrays, perl

I have several huge textfiles which I need to transpose. I get stuck on the idea using Array::Transpose for that purpose - but somehow I can't come to an end...
Here is my source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Array::Transpose;

my $eachline;
my $input=$ARGV[0];
my @array;

open (IN, "<$input") or die ("no such file!");
while(defined($eachline=<IN>))
{
   push @array, split(/\t/,$eachline);
}

my @array2=transpose(\@array);
```

I can not see, what is wrong with that idea, as the documentations says:

```
use Array::Transpose;
@array=transpose(\@array);
```

The error code says:

```
Can't use string ("") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Array/Transpose.pm line 91, <IN> line 3.
```

I am almost new in programming, especially in Perl. I really don't understand what the error means. I am happy with any helpful answer!

Cheers, newbie!

Edit: What I have forgotten to say: My input file says:

```
Parameter1 \t Parameter2 \t .... ParameterXY \n 
Value1 \t Value2...
```

and so on.

I want an output file that says:

```
Parameter1 \t Value1 \t .....ValueXY \n
Parameter2 \t Value2 \t......
```

Comment: My input file says: Parameter1 \t Parameter2 \t .... ParameterXY \n Value1 \t Value2... and so on. I want an output file that says: Parameter1 \t Value1 \t .....ValueXY \n..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to push each row separately.

```
    my @row = split(/\t/,$eachline);
    push @array, \@row;
```

`@row` is a 1-D array. Pushing `\@row` makes a 2-D array. I think you also want a `chomp` to remove line endings.

Full program is

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use Array::Transpose;
    use Data::Dumper;

    my $eachline;
    my $input=$ARGV[0];
    my @array;

    open (IN, "<$input") or die ("no such file!");
    while(defined($eachline=<IN>))
    {
       chomp $eachline ;
       my @row = split(/\t/,$eachline);
       push @array, \@row;
    }

    print Dumper(\@array) ;
    my @array2=transpose(\@array);

    print Dumper(\@array2) ;
```

Another way would be `push @array,  [ split(/\t/,$eachline) ] ;` - the `[ ]` creates an array reference.